# how to update Big Query back-end data on each upload for bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have created the Big Query out of the data I have in my Cloud storage bucket.

In my use case, I am sending data periodically to the same bucket which is backend of my Big Query(while creating the Big query table I used the same bucket name).

> Is it possible to get the updated data into Big Query, as I am pushing new data each time into the same bucket on some interval basis.

Just to mention - I am making native Big query from my dedicated storage bucket mentioned above.

Your help will be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an [external (federated) table on Google Cloud Storage Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage). In this case, whenever you query this table you will get the latest data.

If you just need to append data to a table (let's call it *target table*) based on data from the bucket - I can imagine following this process:

1. Create a federated table on the GCS bucket
2. Setup a simple cron job that runs a `bq` command which is just doing `select * from [federated_table]` and appends results into the target table (you may have a more complicated query that will check duplication of data in the target table and only appends new data).

Alternative option:
Setup a [trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) on your bucket that activates cloud function and in a cloud function you just load the newly added data to the target table.

Comment: Nice. Cloud funtion to Dataflow to BigQuery is also a good option.